# Capturar valor de retorno da query Racket

Tags: lisp

Olá, sou iniciante no racket. Gostaria de capturar o valor **insert-id** que retorna em um uma struct chama [simple-result](https://docs.racket-lang.org/db/query-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._db%2Fbase..rkt%29._simple-result%29%29) da [query](https://docs.racket-lang.org/db/query-api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._db%2Fbase..rkt%29._query%29%29) que executo. O retorno é o seguinte:

```
(simple-result '((insert-id . 30) (affected-rows . 1)))
```

Gostaria de obter o valor **30** por exemplo.

Código da execução da query:

```
(define save_pergunta 
  (lambda (tf_pergunta)
  (define result_save_pergunta (
      query conn "INSERT INTO perguntas VALUES (null, $pergunta)" tf_pergunta))
  (print result_save_pergunta)
  (printf "\nPergunta Cadastrada!\n")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar oque precisava com a função  [dict-ref](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdict..rkt%29._dict-ref%29%29)  passando a query e o identificador como parametros.

Ficando desta forma:

```
(define save_pergunta 
 (lambda (tf_pergunta)
  (define result_save_pergunta (
       dict-ref (
           query conn "INSERT INTO perguntas VALUES (null, $pergunta)" tf_pergunta) 'insert-id)
  (print result_save_pergunta)
  (printf "\nPergunta Cadastrada!\n")))
```